# Can i setup my second ip adress as secondary nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, domain-name, nameserver

I have a server with 2 ip adresses. If i type the first one into my browser i end up with my website. 
62.212.66.33

If i type my second ip adress in the bar i end up somewhere else.
62.212.66.56

Can i set this second ip to act as secondary nameserver. I made NS and a records for the domains. Waited 72 hours. But it returns no records. for dns check.

Is this type of setup possible?

Comment: Are you wanting to setup a second web server?  Your question is confusing.  From what I can tell from the IP addresses you listed, your domain(rdshosting.nl) already has several nameservers setup by leaseweb...  you don't need to setup anymore nameservers.

Comment: I want to remove the leaseweb nameservers and start my own. I want to later add more domains using my own nameserver

Comment: What you need to do is to add a record to dnsnode.net, ns3.rdshosting.nl, with an IP address of 62.212.66.56. They should have a manage DNS web page where you can enter the name and IP address of a third DNS server. This is how you will register the third address. If you have questions about how to do this, send them email, use the live chat, or call them.

Comment: FYI, the in-addr.arpa zones that you have configured will not resolve for anybody else as the zone delegated to your hosting company's DNS servers and not your DNS server. I expect that you will need to ask your hosting company to change those values on case by case basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Bind, then in the named.conf file, add/change the listen-on line to something like this (where the value is the secondary IP address):

```
  listen-on {62.212.66.56; };
```

then configure the zone that you want, such as

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
   type slave;
   file "slave/mydomain.com.slave";
   masters {
             1.2.3.4;
   };
};
```

Where mydomain.com is the domain that you are a secondary for and 1.2.3.4 is the IP address of the primary nameserver.

But what I would suggest that you do is to allow BIND to listen on all your IP addresses. Also, make to add the name & address of your server to the master DNS server, something like:

mydomain.com.       IN NS ns3.mydomain.com
ns3.mydomain.com.   IN A 62.212.66.56

Based on your comment from above, it sounds like what you actually want to do is to run your own DNS, where you are the master.

For that, change the zone def from slave to master and remove the masters clause. Then create your zone data file (use named-xfer, dig, or just type in the information).
Then at your domain registar, change the IP of the DNS server for your domain be your IP address.

Comment: Thank you for the response, you understand my question. I have plesk installed on my server, so bind and named are already configured and installed. I have set up a master with ip 62.212.66.33. Further i don't kno how to add the second ip as slave, I see a section for ACL, can i add the ip adress there? Ans i made 3 records for the ip, an A record for the ip, NS record ns3.mydomain.com, A record for ns3.mydomain.com. I waited 72 hours, but it intodns can still not find it for the domain i used them for. http://intodns.com/centshopper.nl

Comment: If you setup the system as the DNS master, then there no point in setting up the same system as a slave (this would require that you set up a second copy of BIND). I think what you are looking for is a second IP address that you can add to the parent name server (it usually wants IP addresses in pairs). Add the second address to the registar's DNS config and then make sure it is in the DNS zone as well. And then remove after this is done, remove the registars servers and you will be in control of your own DNS.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help. Some thins are clear now to me. I told my registar to change all the nameservers of rdshosting.nl to my own nameservers. This is set up correctly now. The other domain I have still gives me error. http://intodns.com/centshopper.nl

Answer (score 0):

not recommended. but possible.

it's most recommended to have at least 2 dns on separated servers on different network.
preferably, on different datacenter or even on different continent.

beside adding ns and a records,
you must add your ip to your registrar's nameserver list.
some registrars call it 'child nameserver'

without this, your dns will never works.

Comment: Yes but is this possible, i have one on another datacenter, but i was wondering if this is possible and how to set this up. Do you have any suggestions on that

Comment: i usually use nsd for it's small and fast even on small vps.
but you can use any others. bind,djbdns,etc. whatever you feel confortable.